# "uWSGI Error Python application not found" after trying to add a subdomain to Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

Obviously I was wrong to assume adding a subdomain would be as straightforward as duplicating my existing domain & adding a DNS A record.

So I tried to run `cp -r /var/www/mydomain.com/ /var/www/dev.mydomain.com` & configure a subdomain from the original domain settings, but now it gives a 'Python application not found' error on my original domain.

I have a VDS running Ubuntu, Nginx and uWSGI to serve Django with the following configuration;

```
/var/www/mydomain.com
- /conf
-- /nginx.conf
-- /uwsgi.conf
- /logs
- /src
- /venv
```

Nginx is setup to read configs from `/var/www/*/conf/nginx.conf`

uWSGI is set to startup with a Daemon and this is my uwsgi.conf;

```
[uwsgi]
# variables
projectname = mydomain
projectdomain = mydomain.com
base = /var/www/mydomain.com

# config
plugins = python
master = true
protocol = uwsgi
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%(projectname).settings
pythonpath = %(base)/src/%(projectname)
module = %(projectname).wsgi
#module = mydomain.wsgi
#module = mydomain.wsgi:application
#socket = /tmp/%(projectdomain).sock
socket = 127.0.0.1:8889
logto = %(base)/logs/uwsgi.log
# below line runs as a daemon in background
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/mydomain.log
```

And I've pastebined my [uwsgi domain log](http://pastebin.com/k336EpG1) if it helps

I'm still new to uwsgi/nginx (if you hadn't guessed!) so could anyone offer a suggestion for my problem or could I provide some more detail?

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: @singer I'm using 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake here was an improperly renamed module in my Django project.

I changed `mydomain.mydomain` to `mydomain.myd` so then uWSGI was looking for a module named `mydomain.mydomain` and then the `wsgi.py` file instead of `mydomain.myd.wsgi` which is where it had been.